# React Native Unable to build

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle, build

I  am trying to ‘react-native run android’ and I get this error message:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> > - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> >
> >   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> >   >       Could not resolve project :react-native-orientation.
> >   >        Required by:
> >   >            project :app
> >   >       Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-orientation:
> >   >             - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
> >   >       Could not resolve project :@react-native-community_slider.
> >   >        Required by:
> >   >            project :app
> >   >       Unable to find a matching configuration of project :@react-native-community_slider:
> >   >        Required by:
> >   >            project :app
> >   >
> >   > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-webview:
> >   >             - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

This is my settings.gradle file:

```
rootProject.name = 'course'
include ':react-native-os'
project(':react-native-os').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-os/android')
include ':react-native-image-crop-picker'
project(':react-native-image-crop-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker/android')
include ':react-native-firebase'
project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
include ':react-native-filesystem'
project(':react-native-filesystem').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-filesystem/android')
include ':react-native-device-info'
project(':react-native-device-info').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-device-info/android')
include ':react-native-customized-image-picker'
project(':react-native-customized-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-customized-image-picker/android')
include ':react-native-contacts'
project(':react-native-contacts').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-contacts/android')
include ':react-native-cameraroll'
project(':react-native-cameraroll').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-cameraroll/android')
include ':react-native-background-fetch'
project(':react-native-background-fetch').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-background-fetch/android')
include ':react-native-youtube'
project(':react-native-youtube').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-youtube/android')
include ':react-native-orientation'
project(':react-native-orientation').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-orientation/android')
include ':@react-native-community_slider'
project(':@react-native-community_slider').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/slider/android')
include ':react-native-webview'
project(':react-native-webview').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-webview/android')

include ':@react-native-community_cameraroll'
project(':@react-native-community_cameraroll').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,    '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cameraroll/android')
include ':react-native-reanimated'
project(':react-native-reanimated').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android')
include ':react-native-i18n'
project(':react-native-i18n').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-i18n/android')
include ':@react-native-community_async-storage'
project(':@react-native-community_async-storage').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-community/async-storage/android')
include ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include ':react-native-randombytes'
project(':react-native-randombytes').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-randombytes/android')
include ':react-native-sentry'
project(':react-native-sentry').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-sentry/android')
include ':react-native-appsee'
project(':react-native-appsee').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-appsee/android')
include ':react-native-image-resizer'
project(':react-native-image-resizer').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-resizer/android')
include ':react-native-onesignal'
project(':react-native-onesignal').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-onesignal/android')
include ':react-native-mixpanel'
project(':react-native-mixpanel').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-mixpanel/android')
include ':react-native-svg'
project(':react-native-svg').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-svg/android')
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':react-native-fs'
project(':react-native-fs').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fs/android')
include ':react-native-wheel-pick'
project(':react-native-wheel-pick').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-wheel-pick/android')
include ':react-native-fast-image'
project(':react-native-fast-image').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fast-image/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':realm'
project(':realm').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/realm/android')
include ':react-native-camera'
project(':react-native-camera').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-camera/android')
include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')
include ':app'
```

and this is my build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"

    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
           // Local Maven repo containing AARs with JSC library built for Android
          url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
       }
    }
}



subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28 
                buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: it seems your react-native-orientation not resolved if you use a mac, in the terminal; execute `./gradlew build --info', and look at what error info outputs

Comment: from the base folder of my project i get 'build successfull'.

from /android folder I get the same error message as when i execute 'react-native run-android' from the base folder of the project...

Comment: please try to use my suggested command in android studio and lookup detail error info

Comment: do you mean executing `./gradlew build --info' in the terminal of android studio? if so, i get the same error as before...